# `gcloud docker` command refreshing access token on each invocation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

**macOS**

```
Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.27
core 2017.12.08
gcloud
gsutil 4.28
kubectl
```

I have tried revoking the login and logging in again but every command of `gcloud docker` refreshes the access token so it hangs about 30 seconds before actually executing a command.

```
$ gcloud --verbosity=debug docker -- --help                                                                                                                                                      
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.docker] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token

$ gcloud --verbosity=debug docker -- --help                                                                                                                                                          
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.docker] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

#### Login Debug Log

```
$ gcloud --verbosity=debug auth login                                                                        
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.auth.login] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&access_type=offline


INFO: Successfully retrieved access token
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help

You are now logged in as [xxx].
Your current project is [xxx].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
INFO: Display format "none".
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in Linux OS but getting instant response from the same command. Moreover, I tried with other gcloud docker command - gcloud docker --authorize-only and getting an immediate response. Can you please try to execute these command from VM instance and not from the cloud shell?

Comment: @DSaini Hello thank you for commenting. On the VM itself, `gcloud docker --authorize-only` gets an immediate response as well. It's just on my macOS machine that I'm getting this. Just tried reinstalling `gcloud` and clearing my config but still get the same delay. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the feedback. This isolate the issue with respect to Mac OS. Going forward, I would suggest to report this issue as a Customer Issue/Bug on Google public issue tracker(PIT) [platform](https://issuetracker.google.com).